# Inserting timestamp as text into CSV

Tags: java, excel, date, csv, timestamp

I'm trying to insert the values pragmatically in Java into CSV like below format.

```
22:33
33:40
40:40
2:30
```

i want the inserted text to remain as it is, however its simply converting to hh:mm:ss format. As shown below

```
22:33
33:40:00
40:40:00
2:30
```

But, i'm not getting the way to keep the inserted text as it is, in the form of text

Comment: Why do you just do  check before inserting if there is three colons in the string the remove everything after the last one?

Comment: To control how the CSV data is loaded into Excel, you need to "import" the file, not "open" it. When you import text file, you can specify the value separator, e.g. `,` for CSV, and then for each column, you can control the format of the value. Specify `Text` so it doesn't try to interpret the value as a date/time value.